# Fixing vue data map to group by date as well as employee

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I currently have a vue component and template in which I'm listing employees and their hours/scans by date. The problem is my current map is totaling all hours and scans by the first record and it's date.

I need to modify this because my table headers are dates (today, tomorrow and the day after). So I need to be able to use a `v-if` statement for each to compare the date in the column header to the date of the record. In this instance, I should only have one record for employee A123 but I should have 2 records for employee D432 because the two records for that employee have different dates.

How can I also factor date into the unique mapping here?

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    rows: [{
        employee: "A123",
        hours: "15",
        date: "2021-08-31",
        scans: "4"

      },
      {
        employee: "A123",
        hours: "25",
        date: "2021-08-31",
        scans: "4"

      },
      {
        employee: "D432",
        hours: "82",
        date: "2021-09-02",
        scans: "2"

      },
      {
        employee: "D432",
        hours: "40",
        date: "2021-09-01",
        scans: "5"
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    groupByField(list, field) {
      const result = {};
      list.forEach(item => {
        const value = item[field];
        if (value) {
          if (!result[value]) {
            result[value] = [];
          }
          result[value].push(item);
        }
      });
      return result;
    }
  },
  computed: {
    compRows() {
      const a = this.groupByField(this.rows, 'employee');
      let b = Object.values(a)
      return b.map(item => {
        return {
          employee: item[0].employee,
          hours: item.reduce((acc, _item) => (+acc) + (+_item.hours), 0),
          scans: item.reduce((acc, _item) => (+acc) + (+_item.scans), 0),
          date: item[0].date
        }
      })
    }
  }
});
```

```css
th,td{
padding:8px
}
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app" class="container">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Employee</th>
        <th>hours</th>
        <th>scans</th>
        <th>date</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(row, index) in compRows">
        <td>{{row.employee}}</td>
        <td>{{row.hours}}</td>
        <td>{{row.scans}}</td>
        <td>{{row.date}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group based on `employee` and then on `date` and sum up `date` and `scans` in `array#reduce`.

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    rows: [{employee: "A123", hours: "15", date: "2021-08-31", scans: "4" }, { employee: "A123", hours: "25", date: "2021-08-31", scans: "4" }, { employee: "D432", hours: "82", date: "2021-09-02", scans: "2" }, { employee: "D432",hours: "40",date: "2021-09-01",scans: "5"}]
  },
  computed: {
    compRows() {
      const grouped = this.rows.reduce((r, o) => {
        r[o.employee] ??= {};
        r[o.employee][o.date] ??= {employee: o.employee, date: o.date, scans: 0, hours: 0};
        r[o.employee][o.date].scans += +o.scans;
        r[o.employee][o.date].hours += +o.hours;
        return r;
      }, {});
      return Object.values(grouped).map(o => Object.values(o)).flat();
    }
  }
});
```

```css
th,td{
padding:8px
}
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app" class="container">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Employee</th>
        <th>hours</th>
        <th>scans</th>
        <th>date</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(row, index) in compRows">
        <td>{{row.employee}}</td>
        <td>{{row.hours}}</td>
        <td>{{row.scans}}</td>
        <td>{{row.date}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```